# Cant Find the Template to Create a Windows Service in VS 2013 Ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to create a brand new Windows Service project inside VS 2013 Ultimate. However, I don't see "Windows Service" listed under Templates > Visual C# or any other Visual Language. How do I install the Windows Service template?

Answer (score 3):

It is available under

```
Visual C# => Windows Desktop => Windows Services.
```

You can't find it directly under `C#`

Comment: In VS 2015, it's located under ```Visual C# => Windows => Classic Desktop```